# OpenSSL with GOST engine

Tags: openssl, gost3410

I want to use OpenSSL to generate private/public/(Certificate Signing Request) and to sign some data later. But I want to use [OpenSSL GOST engine](http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/engines/ccgost/README.gost).

I downloaded OpenSSL **1.0.0** and modified **openssl.cfg** file:

```
    openssl_conf = openssl_def

    [openssl_def]
    engines = engine_section

    [engine_section]
    gost = gost_section

    [gost_section]
    engine_id = gost
    dynamic_path = ./gost.dll
    default_algorithms = ALL
    CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet
```

I can generate private key and CSR (**single line command string**):

```
    openssl req -newkey gost2001 -pkeyopt paramset:A -passout pass:aofvlgzm \
    -subj "/C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=foo_bar/OU=foo_bar/CN=developer/ \
           emailAddress=vany.egorov@gmail.com" \
    -new > certificate_signing_request.csr
```

I get 2 files:

- certificate_signing_request.csr
- privkey.pem

I know that I can do (prints an (unencrypted) text representation of private and public keys):

```
    openssl genpkey -algorithm gost2001 -pkeyopt paramset:A -text
```

I use GOST instead RSA that is why I cannot just do:

```
    openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem
    Enter pass phrase for privkey.pem:
    6132:error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA:expecting an rsa key:.\crypto\evp\p_lib.c:288:
```

***My question is : how can I generate/get public key (mabye from private key or from csr) using gost?***

I use:

- Windows 7 professional x64;
- OpenSSL 1.0.0;
- **Gost engine**.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

Step by step guide for everyone who wants an alternative to [КРИПТО-ПРО](http://cryptopro.ru/)

**Certificate Signing Request(CSR) + private key**

`./openssl req -newkey gost2001 -pkeyopt paramset:A -passout pass:aofvlgzm -subj "/C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=foo_bar/OU=foo_bar/CN=developer/emailAddress=vany.egorov@gmail.com" -keyout private.key.pem -out csr.csr`

**Sign CSR (csr.csr) with private.key.pem (!!! ADMIN COMMAND PROMT ONLY !!!)**

if not admin: *"unable to write 'random state'"*

`./openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.csr -signkey private.key.pem -out crt.crt`

**Get public key**

`./openssl x509 -inform pem -in crt.crt -pubkey -noout > public.key.pem`

**Get GOST2001-md_gost94 hex**

`./openssl.exe dgst -hex -sign private.key.pem message.xml`

**Get MIME application/x-pkcs7-signature**

`./openssl smime -sign -inkey private.key.pem -signer crt.crt -in message.xml`